# Using multiple log4net file loggers

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have file appenders FileA, FileB, and FileC.  FileA I add to the root element as I want it to be a catch all, (more on this below).  FileB and FileC I use for specific messages and create named loggers for each of those appenders.  In code, I load the log I'm using for most messages like so:

```cs
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

The other loggers, I load like this

```cs
private static readonly log4net.ILog commandLog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerFileB");
```

What's happening is I'm getting what I expect in LoggerFileB, ie, ONLY the special messages.  The problem is these messages also showing up in LoggerFileA, my catch-all I added to root.  I could create a specific named instance for the catch-all, instead of adding it to the root element, but I want the calling type as the logger name in the output.  Creating a named logger means that %logger outputs the name of the log instead of the type.  Is there a way to get precisely what I want (the catchall to show the logger name as the type, but not show messages logged to other named loggers)?  Hopefully I'm missing something and there is a simple solution.

Here's an example of what my log.config looks like for this situation.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="FileA" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="FileA.txt" />
            ...snip...
        </appender>
        <appender name="FileB" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="FileB.txt" />
            ...snip...
        </appender>
        <appender name="FileC" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <file value="FileC.txt" />
            ...snip...
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="LoggerFileA" />
        </root>
        <logger name="LoggerFileB">
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="FileB" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="LoggerFileC">
            <level value="ALL" />
            <appender-ref ref="FileC" />
        </logger>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use set the `additivity` to false:

```
<logger name="LoggerFileB" additivity="false">
```

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks.  I had nearly given up and was about to just go the named logger route.  Glad I asked!  :)

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I had the same question as Tim and your answer helped me!